# Any entire function without zero is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is such a function. Then $|f(z)|>0$ and hence $1/|f(z)|< \infty$. Since $f$ is bounded, by Liouville's theorem it is some constant $C$. By that I conclude than $f(z) = 1/C$ which is constant?

Is this correct?

Comment: Take $z \mapsto e^z$. This is never zero, but is clearly not bounded.

Comment: Just because a function is finite at any particular point does not mean it is bounded, just think of the function $f(z)=z$.

Comment: Just because $|f(z)|<\infty$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ you can't say that $f$ is bounded!

Comment: The result is true if you replace "function" with "polynomial."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not correct, as the counterexample $f(z)=e^z$ shows (already noted in the comments). The fact that $|f(z)|>0$ does not exclude that $|f(z)|$ comes arbitrarily close to $0$, making $\frac{1}{|f(z)|}$ unbounded. Your argument works if there is a constant $c>0$ such that 
$$
|f(z)|\ge c.$$